# Facing a problem on cylinder.

Tags: analytic-geometry, quadrics

I am trying to solve a problem related to quadric surface(cylinder). The problem deals in finding the equation of a right circular cylinder whose guiding curve is a circle which passes through three points, *(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)*.

Now, i know that there is an equation to calculate the equation of a right circular cylinder:

Eq: $(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2+(z-z_1)^2-\frac{\{l(x-x_1)+m(y-y_1)+n(z-z_1)\}^2}{l^2+m^2+n^2}=a^2$  (eq. i)

Now, i know that $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ are the points through which the axial line of the cylinder passes, and $l,m,n$ are the direction ratios of the axial line.

Now, i think, if the three points on the circle is *(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)* , then the coordinates of the center of the circle must be *(0,0,0)*, and since the axial line passes through the center of the circle, hence, $x_1,y_1,z_1 \;must \;be \;equal\; to\; 0$.

Now the symmetric form of the axial line will be: 
$\frac{x}{l}=\frac{y}{m}=\frac{z}{n}$, if so, the i have seen some exercises in the book, where they use 'l' in place of 'x', likewise , 'm' in place of 'y', if it is so, then if we use $x_1=y_1=z_1=0$ and $x=l,y=m,z=n$ in equation (i) above, then it shows error.

This is the problem I am dealing with. Can anybody help me? (actually, this is a proving question , where the required equation of the cylinder is $x^2+y^2+z^2-yz-zx-xy=1$)

Comment: I tend to think the given equation is wrong, except I have made a mistake somewhere. I got $x^2+y^2+(z+1)^2+2xy-yz-zx=2.$ What did *you* obtain?

Comment: i am obtaining error in my approach. Please read "Now the symmetric form" paragraph for clarity.

Comment: What do you mean by "error." Did you use a CAS or something?

Comment: i mean i am getting $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$ which is obviously wrong.

Comment: I see. My equation is also wrong. It doesn't pass through the third point given. I'll check my work again. If I find the error and am able to rectify it, I'll post what I did.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Calling

$$
p_1 = (1,0,0)\\
p_2 = (0,1,0)\\
p_3 = (0,0,1)\\
\vec n = (p_1-p_2)\times(p_3-p_2)\\
p_0 = (x_0,y_0,z_0)
$$

with $\vec n$ normal to the circle and $p_0$ representing the circle's center we have

$$
\cases{
(p_1-p_0)\cdot (p_1-p_0) = r^2\\
(p_2-p_0)\cdot (p_2-p_0) = r^2\\
(p_3-p_0)\cdot (p_3-p_0) = r^2\\
(p_1-p_0)\cdot \vec n = 0
}
$$

Solving those equations for $p_0, r$ we obtain the circle's center and  radius. Once you have $p_0, r$ you can use the equation (eq.i)

Comment: $From\; (p_1-p_0)\cdot \vec n = 0\\\quad\quad we\;get,\;(p_1-p_0)=0, and\;using\;in,\\[10pt]\quad\quad (p_1-p_0)\cdot (p_1-p_0) = r^2\\[10pt]\quad\quad we\;get, r=0.\\[20pt]Radius \;of \;circle\; equal \;to \;0 \;doesn't\;  make\; any\; sense.$

Comment: OP doesn't need a circle. He needs a *cylinder.*

Comment: You are wrong. The solution of the suggested equations give $p_0 = (\frac 13,\frac 13,\frac 13), r = \sqrt{\frac 23}$

Comment: what is wrong in my above approach of $r=0$?